# How to check if a user liked a url

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

Suppose that we put like button on the link "http://myshop.com/product/1"

We want to check if a user click liked on this link "http://myshop.com/product/1" or not.
If user cliked like on this. we will gave some discount for him or give him some reward.

how to do this

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is an Open Graph URL you can check the [`url_like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/) table

```
SELECT user_id FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() and url="THE_URL_TO_CHECK"
```

A successful JSON response would contain the user_id so you should just place a conditional function to return true or false after executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript SDK from facebook. You can read all likes from an user or ask for specific page:

```
FB.api("/me/likes/" + OBJECT_ID, function(response) {
  // Do some staff here with page data
})

FB.api("/me/likes/", function(response) {
  // Do some staff here with all pages data
})
```

You can use the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/likes) in order to test this.

If your case, you need to know your Object ID in the Facebook Open Graph. You can check this in the following [site](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=google.com)